# Directional @ManyToMany but I'd like one side returns unmodifiable(readonly) set

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping

I couldn't think of better question so correct me if I'm wrong.

I have to entities: A and AGroup (in DB they are connected through 3rd table thats relational)

**A.java**

```
[...]
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "As")
    private Set<AGroup> AsGroup = new HashSet<AGroup>();
[...]
```

**AGroup.java**

```
[...]
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(schema = "ars", name = "a_group_rel",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "a_id") })
    private Set<A> As= new HashSet<A>();
[..]
```

Ofc thats working thats not what i mean trying to accomplish.

In **AGroup.java** i have also somethink like this:

```
 public void addA(A a) {
        if (a == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!As.contains(a)) {
            As.add(a);
        }

        if (!a.getAsGroup().contains(this)) {
            a.getAsGroup().add(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeA(A a) {
        as = new HashSet<A>(As);
        as.remove(A);
        a.getAsGroup().remove(this);
    }

    public Set<A> getAs() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(As);
    }
```

And that works too. Now as you can see I'm adding to Set from **A** from **AGroup** method. Now I'd like to put READONLY restriction on `AsGroup` in **A** , e.g by adding in **A**

```
public Set<AGroup> getAsGroup() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(AsGroup);
}
```

But when I do this (for obvious reasons) my methods in **AGroup** (`addA` and `removeA`) will not work. How I can block modification in **A** from all sources exept methods in **AGroup**? I want to add/remove entities in my Sets but only from one direction. In **A** i only want to see entities in `AsGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have:

```
boolean addA(A a) {
    return AsGroup.add(a);
}

boolean removeA(A a) {
    return AsGroup.remove(a);
}
```

And then this methods will be accessible only in this package. If you have proper classes distribution over packages this solution should be OK.

Comment: I dont follow up. Where do you want to put this methods? I assume in **A** cause of AsGroup. I can't remove **A** from AsGroup because its holding **AsGroup** not A . So how this fix me issue? I still have to return modifiable set in **A** in order to add group in **AsGroup** methods.

Comment: but i want AsGroup in **A** to hold AsGroup beans. I can't add there **A**. Even if i change it to addAsGroup(AsGroup asGroup) this method will be accesible somewhere else if someone declare **A**. I dont get your solution and how it will help, some info would be nice ;) boolean methods are accesible only in package? not to mention even if this somehow works (i dont understand now somehow) someone that will call a.getAsGroup() will be able to modify this set